# sas macro do loop and ampersand to subset dataset

Tags: list, loops, macros, sas

In the macro below, how do I automate selecting cars from sashelp.cars in my data step. I think it involves ampersands 
           %let dsn = &inDsn;
....

```
       %macro subset_by_make (dsn=,carList=);

    %let car_n = %sysfunc(countw(&carList, ' '));

    %do i = 1 %to &car_n;
    %let make = %scan (&carList, &i, ' ');
    data cars_&make;
        set sashelp.cars(where = (make = "&make"));
    run;
    proc print data=cars_&make;
    run;
%end;
 %mend subset_by_make;
 %subset_by_make(dsn=sashelp.cars, carList= Acura Toyota);
```

Would appreciate any help
Maggie

Comment: What's your overall goal here? Creating lots of separate datasets like this is usually a very bad idea, as it complicates your code - you should aim to use by-group processing instead in almost all situations.

Comment: http://blogs.sas.com/content/publishing/2015/01/30/sas-authors-tip-getting-the-macro-language-to-perform-a-do-loop-over-a-list-of-values/

Comment: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/62086/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001360983.htm

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for any macro code at all here if all you want to do is print out the cars dataset grouped by make:

```
proc sort data = sashelp.cars out = cars;
by make;
run;

proc print data = cars;
where make in ('Acura','Toyota');
by make;
run;
```

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to write macros, do loop is an important topic. Is there another way to this exercise using the macro language and the by statement? Also, would really like to know how to select cars from sashelp.cars when I subset the data.

Comment: @Margaret What does this mean "would really like to know how to select cars from sashelp.cars when I subset the data"? Are you trying to obtain a list of all the make? How to filter your table? What if the MAKE value has a space in it?

Answer (score 0):

Reeza, sorry my question is confusing. I wanted to create various datasets called cars_acura, cars_toyota, etc. from sashelp.cars

Below, I think I have found a solution. Thanks everyone for your help!

```
%macro subset_by_make (lib=,inDsn=,carList=);

    %let car_n = %sysfunc(countw(&carList, ' '));

    %do i = 1 %to &car_n %by 1;
        %let make = %scan (&carList, &i, ' ');      
      title "dataset: &inDsn._&make";
        data &inDsn._&make;
            set &lib..&inDsn(where = (make = "&make"));
        run;
        proc print data=cars_&make;
        run;
    %end;
%mend subset_by_make;
%subset_by_make(lib=sashelp,inDsn=cars,carList= Acura Toyota);
```